# Possible to change the scale of form designer (of mobile device simulator)

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-xe6

I'm using FMX framework of Delphi XE6 to develop a webapp for iPad. The form looks extremely large, so that the whole form cannot be shown entirely on 24' TFT monitor. If I want to add control to the form bottom, I have to scroll down first. I found one thing very annoying.

**Is it possible to scale the form to 50%?** On MacOS, I can easily scale the window of the iOS simulator by pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to fit it too your screensize you schould set the align properties to Client rather then give it a size. This way it scales automaticly to your screensize. If you have more components on your form you should change all of them too align in the way you want and maybe use layouts.

Comment: The issue is related to form designed (in IDE). When program is compiled, everything is fine. I think it is a IDE setting issue, not a programming related question at all.

Comment: @stanleyxu2005 you can set Scale property of the form to scale it up or down.

Comment: The property will not be remembered when I restart the IDE (at least XE6)

Comment: I'm using XE8 atm and I don't have that problem. Maybe you should upgrade.